# Using tensorflow/keras directly inside MATLAB?

Tags: c++, matlab, api, tensorflow, keras

Is there any way I can use TensorFlow or Keras inside Matlab directly?

Either using the C++/Python API of TensorFlow or converting the model to a compatible format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are importers to bring your tensorflow/keras networks into MATLAB. There is quite bit material on how you can do that. here are few of them

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/64649-deep-learning-toolbox-importer-for-tensorflow-keras-models

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0XywJP_TnCI

Once you import your networks into MATLAB, you can use these networks like MATLAB native Deep learning networks.

Hope this helps.