# How to call a a Python code that describe a Keras-Tensorflow model from Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I was running into a situation where I have build a deep neural network (no convolution) using Tensorflow-keras but I was unable to import the model into matlab.

This is my model

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28]))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(300, activation="elu", kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(300, activation="elu", kernel_initializer = 'he_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
```

My progress so far

```
clc;
modelfile = 'keras_neural_fashion_MNIST_Nadam.h5';

net = importKerasNetwork(modelfile)
```

Return an error

```
Error using importKerasNetwork (line 94)
Unable to import network because some network
layers are not yet supported. To import layers
and weights, call importKerasLayers with
'ImportWeights' set to true.
Error in import_keras (line 5)
net = importKerasNetwork(modelfile)
```

Is there anyway for me to call that piece of python code that contain the tensorflow-keras model from the main matlab program ?

Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using tensorflow/keras directly inside MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53643648/using-tensorflow-keras-directly-inside-matlab)

Comment: Not really, I follow that post and run into some errors, I will update my post ?